# The nature of time, according to quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spacetime, time, virtual-particles, wave-particle-duality

I will try my best to ask the question that best fits something I have been pondering on for a few days.

> **Are virtual particles really constantly popping in and out of
>   existence? Or are they merely a mathematical bookkeeping device for
>   [quantum field theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory)?**
>
> Gordon Kane, director of the Michigan Center for Theoretical Physics
>   at the University of Michigan at Ann Arbor, provides this answer.
>
> Virtual particles are indeed real particles. Quantum theory predicts
>   that every particle spends some time as a combination of other
>   particles in all possible ways. These predictions are very well
>   understood and tested.
>   http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=are-virtual-particles-rea

We define a second by the "*duration of 9,192,631,770 periods of the radiation corresponding to the transition between the two hyperfine levels of the ground state of the caesium 133 atom*" (from wikipedia). Or in other words, we define a second by movement of a certain amount of waves/particles.

Since virtual particles pop in and out of existence, could you still claim that these things have a movement on the quantum level? If not, then how do you explain time/spacetime in the eyes of quantum field theory? And how does quantum entanglement fit in to this picture?

I am not a scientist, so please forgive me if my understandings of these concepts are flawed.

Comment: More on the concept of time: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16688/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15371/2451

Answer (score 4):

1. Virtual particles do not pop in and out of existence - this is just a common misconception. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/22064/7924 and Chapter A8 of my 
   [theoretical physics FAQ](https://arnold-neumaier.at/physfaq/physics-faq.html).
2. The second is defined by a measurement procedure that can easily and reliably be replicated, not by reference to vague concepts.
3. In quantum field theory (as opposed to quantum gravity), time is simply a parameter that together with position serves as argument for the fields. Further explanation is neither given nor needed.
4. This has nothing to do with entanglement.